# Creating Custom CaptureView Material Design using Storyboard

Tags: cosmicmind

I am working with the material capture view and I was wondering if there was a way to implement this using a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, as the CaptureView is a collection of views that would need to be handled in Storyboards. We are making big updates to Audio, Video, and Photo this month that should make using Storyboards more simple.